# Need SSL to support Facebook authentication on my site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ssl

I am making a Rails site that lets people sign in, only using Omniauth authentication with Facebook. No passwords are entered into my site. Is it still beneficial to have SSL on my site? Or does the Facebook authentication route pretty much take care of that? I know SSL is required for Facebook apps/sites that appear in FB, and that is NOT my case.

I know it *will* work, just like I can have a login screen with email/password without SSL. It will work, but it's not exactly secure. I'm looking for a recommendation... if I don't have SSL on my site, what info is passed that would not be secure? And is that info worth having my own SSL certificate to hide it from anyone watching?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: It will work fine without SSL even if your app user has secure browsing enabled.

Answer (score 0):

its an ipage, when browsed via HTTPS it displays an error